# Android: Get entire column data

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to get the data of an entire column into a string array. My database contains two columns Id and Names. I want to read all the entries of the names column and put it into a array. Please help.

EDIT #1:
Im using the following code but i can get only one name with this code.

```
String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_APPS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            name = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            name = null;
        }
            db.close();
```

Comment: First Try Something,if you could not get the answer then share your effort and ask help. We will ready to help you. Anyhow,Try This: Run the select query and get the result in cursor.Get the cursor count  and initialize the array with size cursor count. Now Iterate the cursor and put into .

Comment: you are not performing any loop to get all the values from table.The if statement excutes only once,so only you are getting only one name

Comment: @krishna,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808829/adding-multiple-column-values-from-db-into-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int total=0;
    Cursor csr=sdb.query("tablename", null, null,null,null,null,null);
    csr.moveToFirst();
    while(!csr.isAfterLast())
    {
        total++;
         csr.moveToNext();
    }

    String strarray[] = new String[total];

    Cursor csrs=sdb.query("tablename", null, null,null,null,null,null);
    csrs.moveToFirst();
    int aray=0;
    while(!csrs.isAfterLast())
    {
        strarray[aray]=csrs.getString(1);
        aray++;
        csrs.moveToNext();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work. When i run the app it says [Ljava.lang.String;@41852260

Comment: Ljava.lang.String;@ is returned where you used string arrays as strings.

Comment: Worked wrote a loop to get the data. Thanks

Comment: Can I get all values and not just last entry?