# How can I get the entire column from sqlite table using a cursor?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have an a String Array called Collections.

```
String[] Collections;
```

I have integer values saved in my db table. I want to grab the integer values from my database column called specific_collections.

and set that to an integer array SpecificCollections.

So, I want to set it up like this:

```
String[] Collections = 0;
Integer[] SpecificCollections = getColumnValuesFromSpecificCollectionsColumn();
```

After I set them to an integer array, I want to parse the integer array and save each int value to my String Array that is something of the form below:

```
Collections = new String[]{Collection.SpecificCollections.fromInt(SpecificCollections[i]).getString()};
```

where Specific Collections is the array of integers from db.

EDIT: Here's what I have so far but it's only populating the list with one int?

```
ArrayList<Integer> regionList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
 Cursor cursorTwo = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT region FROM collection", null);
            if (cursorTwo != null && cursorTwo.getCount() != 0) {
                cursorTwo.moveToFirst();  
                while (!cursorTwo.isAfterLast()) {
                    regionList.add(cursorTwo.getInt(0));
                    cursorTwo.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            for (Integer inte : regionList){
                regions = new String[]{Collection.Regions.fromInt(inte).getString()};
            }
```

Is below the correct way to iterate through an array list and pass the distinct integers inside the fromInt() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQLiteDatabase.query() method, set selection and selectionArgs parameters to null. see the following code for example:

```
String[] projection = { COLUMN_NAME }
Cursor cursor = mSQLiteDb.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);

ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        values.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to query using cursor? I tried a few solutions but none are working. Only the last value is shown. I tried this solution but doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852821/android-get-entire-column-data#comment42194295_19852821

Comment: hmmm, can you explain how it doesn't work? any error messages or something? I updated my answer, please try the code.

Comment: What is setNumValue? What should be myObject in this case?

Comment: You can ignore myObject, i added it to show you that you can store the columns' returned values anywhere. I updated the code again and replaced myObject with an arraylist of integers

Comment: do not forget to close cursor.

Comment: @Abdullah, please see my edit. I think your method is right but for some reason my list is only populating with one value?

Comment: @Euridice01 what is that reason..?i mean you are saying "for some reason it is giving one value" ?

Comment: I don't know the reason? It should give 2 values not 1.

Comment: try replacing your line `regionList.add(cursorTwo.getInt(0));` with the line `regionList.add(cursorTwo.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISTINCT)));`