# How to use a sum query to construct a getTotal method in sqlite database adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite

Would anybody be able to help me construct a public getTotal() method from the following sqlite db adapter java file?

I want to use this method to return a single value for the total of the 'amount' column for all records added.

The only method constructing options I can find are based on cursors, which returns a whole row. I want a method which returns a single value which can then be called and displayed in a TextView.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
 public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
 private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

//set name of database and table
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EventDB";
private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Donor";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
       "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
               KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
               KEY_NAME + "," +
               KEY_AMOUNT + " numeric," +
               KEY_EMAIL + "," +
               " UNIQUE (" + KEY_EMAIL +"));";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
     db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
             + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
     onCreate(db);
  }
  }

 public DonorsDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

public DonorsDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
  mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
}

public void close() {
  if (mDbHelper != null) {
     mDbHelper.close();
   }
 }

public long createDonor(String name, double amount,
                         String email) {

  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

  initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  initialValues.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
  initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);

  return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }
```

Comment: Dude Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852821/android-get-entire-column-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int getTotalAmount() {
    int amount = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + KEY_AMOUNT +") FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE , null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    db.close();
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this but I'm getting a cannot resolve getReadableDatabase problem

Comment: just put it in `DatabaseHelper` class

Comment: I put it into the DatabaseHelper class and this solved it -- but I can't access from anywhere because the class is private. Sorry if I'm being really inept but I am modifying somebody else's code and I am new to android.

Comment: It's fine -- I just needed to declare mydbHelper = new DonorsDbAdapter.DatabaseHelper(this); in the external java class I was using! Thanks very much your help was superb.

Answer (score 1):

you should execute this query and replace `table_name` with your table's name.

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table_name;
```